# drag and drop html5 quiz result not incrementing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

am trying to develop a quiz snippet with drag and drop and end up with this code where its always showing result as 1 the result is not incrementing.....

i tried many ways but its not incrementing.....

javascript:

here is my code which i used in the

```
 <script>
    function allowDropi(ev)
    {
        ev.preventDefault();
    }

    function dragi(ev)
    {
        ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
    }

    function dropi(ev)
    {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
        ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));

        result1=0;

        if(ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text")==="drag2i")
        {
            result1++;

        }


        if(ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text")==="dra2i")
        {
            result1++;
        }


        if(ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text")==="dr2i")
        {
            result1++;
        }


        if(ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text")==="2i")
        {
            result1++;
        }


        if(ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text")==="d2i")
        {
            result1++;
        }

         document.getElementById('boldStuff6').innerHTML = result1;
    }

    alert(result1);

    </script>
```

where am i going wrong please check mycode and help me in getting the result...

Comment: hi i need one more favor that i cannt restrict the drop box to one image can u suggest any changes please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that everytime you call this function result **is being set to 0** by "result1=0" and then you are incremeting it afterwards.

If you want to keep count of the result you will neet to make result as a property of the function.

instead of **"result1=0"** add:

```
this.result1 = ( this.result1  ) ? this.result1 : 0; // this will make sure it keeps old stored values from last time you call the function.
```

and change your incrementers to the following:

```
this.result1++; // or you can use ++this.result1; or even this.result1+=1;
```

I hope that answers your question.

thanks,
Miter

Comment: thanks for the replay its working my mistake i didnt see it ..... your  awesome bro....

Comment: hi i need one more favor that i cannt restrict the drop box to one image can u suggest any changes please...

Comment: Could you please try to explain better your question ?

Comment: the snippet which am trying to develop is a drag and drop quiz where user need to drag out the odd one of the options so i provided a drop box to drop the odd one which is now taking more than one but it should only take one option so can u help me in restricting it one..